# Cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)

Tags: reactjs

I've checked other solutions here before posting it, but I wasn't able to do a fix. What i want to do is each time `currentState` changes to call the Hook and apply to the `all` state the object of Questions with the number `currentState` it gives to it.

For example this dump data:

```
[
 {
  title: 'hello world'
 },
 {
  title: 'hello human'
 }
]
```

So when the `currentState` is 1, to fetch the first object from question and add to `all` state.

Here is my effect:

```
import Questions from './dataJSON'

const [all, setAll] = useState([])


useEffect(() => {
        setAll(...all, Questions[currentQuestion - 1])
    }, [currentQuestion])
```

`currentQuestion` is 0 at the start because I don't want to fetch the Question, until the counter is 2, in this case the default `currentQuestion` state is 1.

I've tried a lot of things, actually now getting this error: `TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`

Comment: Either `currentQuestion` or `Questions` is not defined. Try logging out both.

Comment: I don't think so, they do both return a value, ```currentState = 0```, while Questions does contain data.

Comment: you should iterate the array like this `setAll[...all, Questions[currentQuestion - 1]]`

Comment: doesn't work, i copied paste

Answer (score 0):

The Solution is that you can't iterate with setAll the objects without having the [].

```
useEffect(() => {
  var seperate = questions[currentQuestion -1];
  setAll([...all, seperate])
}, [currentQuestion])
```

Comment: Don't forget to explain what the solution actually does and to mark this as the chosen answer